# Unable to view table due to LOCK

Tags: mysql

How would I release the LOCK in the following error message?

```
MySQL said: Table 'item_creation' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

This is what shows when I try and view the table. First, what does this mean? And second, how can I fix this error? Usually what I'm doing is restarting mysql.

Note: this is occurring after doing a database import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us the matching LOCK TABLES statement.  Are you using MyISAM tables?  What version of MySQL are you running?

Look at the intervening statements; were any DDL statements?  Are you running on Windows?  ALTER TABLE may unlock the table.  Don't do ALTER between LOCK and UNLOCK.

Did the connection timeout and disconnect, then automatically reconnect?  The disconnect would have released the locks.  Consider turning off auto-reconnect.